# Android App Widget - Full List of supported Views

Tags: android, view, widget

What views are supported in a Android App Widget?

Unfortunately, the list at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html is not complete...

Answer (score 1):

The full list of supported Views is:

In the documentation

```
AdapterViewFlipper 
Button
Chronometer
FrameLayout
GridLayout
GridView
ImageButton
ImageView
LinearLayout
ListView
ProgressBar
RelativeLayout
StackView 
TextView
ViewFlipper
```

Not in the documentation:

```
DateTimeView
TextClock
```

Notice: DateTimeView is available in the Android Source code, but not in the SDK. It might work, when used properly from XML (IDE will show errors)

Deprecated:

```
AbsoluteLayout
AnalogClock
```

Comment: There is no `DateTimeView` in the Android SDK. Also, I am curious as to how you have determined that `TextClock` is safe in a `RemoteViews`.

Comment: i checked the source code of the RemoteViews and basically every view, which has a @RemoteView annotation (and is availlable from the Launcher) should work. I checked all View implementations in the Android Source, it seems like, DateTimeView is in the sources, but not in the SDK, you're right...